# What's the usage of action do_meta_boxes?

Tags: actions

```
/**
 * Fires after meta boxes have been added.
 *
 * Fires once for each of the default meta box contexts: normal, advanced, and side.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string  $post_type Post type of the post.
 * @param string  $context   string  Meta box context.
 * @param WP_Post $post      Post object.
 */
do_action( 'do_meta_boxes', $post_type, 'normal', $post );
```

I found these in `wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php` and I can't figure out  purpose of these actions ( checked for add_action( 'do_meta_boxes' ... ) there is no such actions ).

Documentation says

> Fires after meta boxes have been added.
>
> Fires once for each of the default meta box contexts: normal,
>   advanced, and side.

But what's purpose is for these action? When should I use these actions?

**NOTE:** it's not the same as `do_meta_boxes()` function and has nothing common with it!

Comment: `do_meta_boxes` Can be used to manipulate the previously registered meta boxes but before they are echoed. It fires after `add_meta_boxes` hook.

Comment: `add_meta_boxes` can be used to manipulate previosly registred meta boxes to... i.e. that there should be some othere reason why they puted these action..

Comment: Dont get you.. what i'm saying is that
`add_meta_boxes` - registering of metabox
`do_meta_boxes` - displaying metabox

Comment: `do_meta_boxes` hook isn't for displaying meta boxes.. `do_meta_boxes` function is for displaying meta boxes..
if you try to echo something in `do_meta_boxes` hook it will show an error `headers already sent`.

Comment: Again, `do_meta_boxes` hook fires when meta box have been added but before echoed. You can test it, for example, to remove the "featured image" meta_box from your editor. `function test_callback($page, $context, $post){
   remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', $page, $context );  
}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'test_callback', 10,3 );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25433#comment:2):

> [The] do_meta_boxes [action] is designed to let people manipulate the registered meta boxes once they are registered but before they are rendered.

So the `do_meta_boxes` hook is not for doing (that is: displaying) the meta boxes. This is because:

> When the do_meta_boxes actions was moved out of do_meta_boxes() it should have had its name changed.  add_meta_boxes was added in 3.0 to be the hook that we should have renamed do_meta_boxes to be.